# Looking for Power Supply programmable in C/C++ via USB-COM?

Tags: power-supply

I was trying to find a programmable power supply to help me benchmark a bunch of brushless motors. But seems I cannot find any. Most have their own IDE or meta-language. It seems like most power supplies are programmable, but in an environment that cannot communicate in real time with other non-power supply devices. So I do not need the ability to program the power supply, **I want the ability to send directly instructions to the power supply using a C interface from a more complex C program from my PC.**

Also C++ is ok.

I think it is perfectly reasonable to assume somewhere I can find something like:

- up to 15 V CV output
- up to 15 A CC output
- 220 V AC input  (domestic supply)
- programmable directly with C/C++ library.

Ideally I'd like to connect to my PC using USB.

- My Arduino, driving the ECS
- The Power supply
- **Power supply and Arduino are NOT connected directly**

And then use a program like that to perform my benchmark.

```
int main()
{
    /*Arduino function I wrote that runs on PC*/
    ArmESC(COM_PORT_A); 
    Wait(6000);


    /* Power supply driver*/
    SetVoltage(12, COM_PORT_B);
    SetMaxCurrent(10,COM_Port_B);
    Wait(1000);


    /*Arduino function I wrote that runs on PC*/
    SetRPM(3000,COM_PORT_A);

    Wait(1000);


    /* Power supply driver*/
    int Power = ReadPower(COM_PORT_B);
    Wait(1000);
    int Power2 = ReadPower(COM_PORT_B);

    printf("Power:%s",Power2-Power);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't look too much at power. I just need a power supply that can provide enough power to **run 1 brushless motors and its connected propeller, to a realistic number of RPM.**

Comment: That sounds like a multi-thousand piece of equipment to me. Just sayin' since you're using an Arduino that you might be budget constrained.

Comment: Aside from the 3000w option, theres tons of cheaper units that can do that.  YouTube is full of reviews of the latest smart power supplies.  If you really need that kind of power though you might be paying more.

Comment: Do you actually mean 3000W? 15A * 15V = 225W.

Comment: The 3000 w was my domestic supply( if you look at previous edits it was marked as input, not output, I removed because it seems it makes confusion). The brushless motors I want to test are all under 200w so a power supply with more than 200 should be able to sustain that power for a long time. ( I don't want to burn my supply :/ :P)

Comment: Ah sure. Ahah. Exactly .. some Power supplies limit their voltage if the current reach the limit. So I'd expect to be able to obtain the same from a programmable Power Supply...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power supplies that can be commanded via for example RS232 or USB interface do exist. Just send control commands from Arduino via RS232 or from PC over serial adapter and you have a power supply that can be programmed with C/C++.

Comment: I was suspecting that It existed, but which ones?Maybe of you could provide a couple of examples I may be able to refine my searches furtherly. Sometimes I may be missing a keyword for googling correctly. Also note I prefer to avoid command the Power supply directly from Arduino, I don't think I can add more code to Arduino the memory Is almost full that's why I want to send commands from PC directly.

Comment: Asking what to buy is off topic. But I put "lab psu rs232" and "lab psu usb control" as search terms.

Comment: I spent the whole day trying to find one, so any tip on search terms is welcome.. in example, using "PSU" looks promising. I'll let you know. Thank you man.

Comment: What made my day. Also using keyword "SDK"